# How to prevent UISlider from jumping into place while snapping/stepping

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uislider

I have a UISlider that snaps into 5 different places.

```
slider.minimumValue = 1
slider.maximumValue = 5
```

The snapping works fine but it's abrupt and doesn't smoothly snap into place. It sort of "jumps" into place

I tried animating the scroll (didn't work):

```
@objc func onSliderValChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.slider.value = round(sender.value)
        self.slider.setValue(round(sender.value), animated: true)
    }
}
```

I also tried adding a panGesture (didn't work):

```
panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGestureHandler(_:)))
slider.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

@objc func panGestureHandler(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer){

    let currentPoint = recognizer.location(in: slider)
    let percentage = currentPoint.x/slider.bounds.size.width

    let delta = Float(percentage) * (slider.maximumValue - slider.minimumValue)
    let value = slider.minimumValue + delta
    slider.setValue(round(value), animated: true)
}
```

**How can I achieve the slider to smoothly scroll but still snap into place?**

Here's the original code without the above tries:

```
let slider: UISlider = {
    let slider = UISlider()
    slider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    slider.minimumValue = 1
    slider.maximumValue = 5
    slider.value = 3
    slider.isContinuous = true
    slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onSliderValChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    return slider
}()

@objc func onSliderValChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {

    slider.value = round(sender.value)
}

func setAnchors() {
    slider.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    slider.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    slider.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `UISlider` draws itself using several `UIImageView` subviews. When you change the slider's `value`, the slider sends itself `setNeedsLayout`, but it doesn't actually change the frames of its subviews until it receives `layoutSubviews` during the layout phase of the run loop.

To animate the change in value, you need to make the slider lay out its subviews inside your animation block. Thus:

```
@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ slider: UISlider) {
    slider.value = round(slider.value)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        slider.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

Comment: How'd you know to pick the number 0.2? I tried other numbers and that works the best

Comment: Just experience.

Comment: 0.25 also works very well, that’s what ended going with, it’s a little smoother over the slider steps/snaps for my app. Try it when you can. Peace